# Reading HadUK-Grid (NetCDF) files into R and covert into dataframe

Tags: r, netcdf, ncdf4

Data read in from: https://data.ceda.ac.uk/badc/ukmo-hadobs/data/insitu/MOHC/HadOBS/HadUK-Grid/v1.1.0.0/region/tasmin/day/v20220310

## Read daily min temp data in

```
nc <- nc_open("xxxxx")     
print(nc)

*Time variable info printed....*     
    time  Size:22281`    
    axis: T`    
    bounds: time_bounds
    units: hours since 1800-01-01 00:00:00  
    standard_name:time    
    calendar: gregorian
```

## Convert variables

```
region <- ncvar_get(nc, "geo_region")    
temp <- ncvar_get(nc, "tasmin")    
time <- nc.get.time.series(f = nc,    
                correct.for.gregorian.julian = TRUE,    
                time.dim.name = "time")
```

## Issue

What is the best way to get this fie into a usable DF of daily regional temperatures? I am not sure if I have converted the time variable right either as end in November 2021 but should be December.

Comment: The tidync package is specifically designed for converting netcdf to dataframe. I recommend checking it out

Comment: Unfortunately, one cannot access the dataset without registration. However, you should be able to solve this using `{terra}` via `rast("your_file.nc") |> as.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the file and I got a time dimension of 22,646 observations.

With the [`CFtime` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=CFtime) you can easily deal with the time dimension in climate observation files like this:

```
library(CFtime)

nc <- nc_open("./tasmin_hadukgrid_uk_region_day_19600101-20211231.nc")

# Use CFtime to read in the time dimension from the file.
cf <- CFtime(nc$dim$time$units, nc$dim$time$calendar, nc$dim$time$vals)

# Get the dates as a character vector
dates <- CFtimestamp(cf)

# The "geo_region" variable has the names of the administrative units
region <- ncvar_get(nc, "geo_region")

# Read the data, transpose to get regions in columns and dates in rows
tasmin <- t(ncvar_get(nc, "tasmin"))
nc_close(nc)

# Set the dimnames on the array
dimnames(tasmin) <- list(dates, region)

# Convert the array to a data.frame
tasmin <- as.data.frame(tasmin)
```